# Microsoft To Do on iPhone tries to sign in with the wrong enterprise account

Tags: ios, microsoft

I use Microsoft To Do. I am fresh out of university, and I wish to use my employee account, as that syncs easily to the work computer. But I encounter a problem. I am using an iPhone 8 running iOS 15.6.1.

It goes as follows:

1. I open Microsoft To Do on my iPhone. and I see a list of accounts to sign into. Two in my case: My university account, and my company account.
2. I tap my company account.
3. The iPhone switches briefly to Microsoft authenticator
4. …and then greets me with my university's login page, instead of my company's login page
5. This prevents me from using the app.

Hope one of you has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my school account was not properly removed from the authentication app. So doing that, plus rebooting the phone seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: This isn’t a simple case. You can also end up with ADAL items in the iOS keychain that point to a previous credential. Thanks for asking and answering.